# Laravel Stormpath not able to access User Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stormpath

I am using Laravel and Stormpath for User Management. I am able to register and login user successfully using `AJAX`.

After successful login only the url is returned to AJAX, but after login when I go to User specific pages I am not able to fetch User Data.

Registration and Login happens in `RegisterController`
User Pages are rendered using `UserController`

I've tried to get User data using

```
$user = app('stormpath.user');
```

in UserController, but when I  do `dd($user)` **`null`** is returned.

How to persist or get User Data after successful login or sign-up in other Controllers?

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Stormpath Laravel integration, when you run AJAX calls, we do not set any cookies.  We provide you with the JWT in the header response that you will need to look at and then store them youself.  The JWT will then need to be attached to all other requests as a Bearer token which will allow you to use the `$user = app('stormpath.user') method to get the user information out of the JWT.

Comment: I am able to set `access_token` in cookie but when I attach `middleware('stormpath.auth')` to the user route I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::bearerToken()`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: In my `composer.json` it shows `5.1.*` ah I can't find `bearerToken()` in `https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html`

Comment: We dont officially support Laravel 5.1,  we only support 5.2 an 5.3 right now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got everything working. Thank you @bretterer

```
// Stormpath user account creation
\Stormpath\Client::$apiKeyProperties = "apiKey.id="
       .env('STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID').
       "\napiKey.secret=".env('STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET');

$client = \Stormpath\Client::getInstance();
$apps = $client->tenant->applications;
$apps->search = array('name' => 'My Application');
$application = $apps->getIterator()->current();
$account = \Stormpath\Resource\Account::instantiate(
    [
        'givenName'       => $request->input('username'),
        'middleName'      => '',
        'surname'         => 'StromTrooper',
        'username'        => $request->input('username'),
        'email'           => $request->input('user_mail'),
        'password'        => $request->input('user_pass'),
        'confirmPassword' => $request->input('user_pass')
    ]
 );

// Create User Account and Log-in the User
try
{
   $response = $application->createAccount($account);

   $passwordGrant = new \Stormpath\Oauth\PasswordGrantRequest(
        $request->input('user_mail'), 
        $request->input('user_pass')
   );

   $auth = new \Stormpath\Oauth\PasswordGrantAuthenticator($application);

   $result = $auth->authenticate($passwordGrant);

   $atoken = cookie("access_token", 
                    $result->getAccessTokenString(), 
                    $result->getExpiresIn()
                   );
   $rtoken = cookie("refresh_token", 
                     $result->getRefreshTokenString(),
                     $result->getExpiresIn()
                    );
   $response_bag['success'] = url('userprofile');

 }
 catch (\Stormpath\Resource\ResourceError $re)
 {
       $response_bag['error'] = $re->getMessage();
       $atoken = 'null';
       $rtoken = 'null';           
 }

 return response()
      ->json($response_bag)
      ->withCookie($atoken)
      ->withCookie($rtoken);
```

and in the User controller I am able to access the user details using `app('stormpath.user');`

and since I was using `Laravel 5.1`
I had to comment out `$token = $request->bearerToken();` from `vendor/stormpath/laravel/src/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` from function `public function isAuthenticated(Request $request)`